# I would like to make 'function of User authentication' in Laravel-Breeze and Docker+React.js Application

Tags: reactjs, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I would like to make the title function.
So, I would like to do POST User information to Laravel-side.
but Chrome(MacOS) send message on developer tool what is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT".

I world like to regist user info to Laravel-side and MySQL DB of Laravel.

Please help me.

Laravel get on Laravel-sail.

Under code is React side code.

```
import '../Register.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Register = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [confirmEmail, setConfirmEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const sendInfo = () => {
    const nameInput = document.getElementById('user-name');
    const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
    const confirmEmailInput = document.getElementById('confirm-email');
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');

    if (nameInput && emailInput && confirmEmailInput && passwordInput) {
      const userNameValue = nameInput.value;
      const emailValue = emailInput.value;
      const confirmEmailValue = confirmEmailInput.value;
      const passwordValue = passwordInput.value;

      if (userNameValue.trim() === '' || emailValue.trim() === '' || passwordValue.trim() === '' || confirmEmailValue.trim() === '') {
        alert('全ての項目は必須です。');
      } else {
        setUserName(userNameValue);
        setEmail(emailValue);
        setConfirmEmail(confirmEmailValue);
        setPassword(passwordValue);
      }
    } else {
      alert('入力項目が見つかりません。');
    }

    const url = 'http://0.0.0.0:80/register';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // POSTメソッドとAPIのエンドポイントを指定してリクエストを初期化
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    // リクエストヘッダーを設定
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // リクエストの状態が変わったときのイベントハンドラを設定
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // リクエストが完了し、レスポンスが成功だった場合
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);  // レスポンスをコンソールに出力
        }
    };

    // 送信するデータを設定
    var data = [
      userName,
      email,
      confirmEmail,
      password
    ];

    // リクエストを送信
    xhr.send(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-content">
      <h1 className='user-auth'>ユーザー登録</h1>
      <div className='form'>
        <form className="user-info">
          <h1 className='form-content'>ユーザー名</h1>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="user-name"
            id="user-name"
            placeholder='ユーザー名' //User-name
            required
          />
        </form>
        <form className="user-info">
          <h1 className='form-content'>メールアドレス</h1>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="mail"
            id="email"
            placeholder='メールアドレス' //E-mail
            required
          />
          <h1 className='form-content'>確認用メールアドレス</h1>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="confirm-mail"
            id="confirm-email"
            placeholder='確認用メールアドレス'//confirm E-mail(In Japanese)
            required
          />
          <h1 className='form-content'>パスワード</h1>
          <input
            type="current-password"
            name="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder='パスワード' //password(In Japanese)
            required
          />
        </form>
        <a
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn--orange"
          onClick={sendInfo}
        >
          登録 //Regist
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

And the under code is Dockerfile of the React side.

```
FROM alpine:latest

# 必要なパッケージのインストール
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache nodejs npm

# Node.jsのインストール
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm

# Reactの環境構築
RUN npm install -g create-react-app

# アプリケーションのディレクトリを作成
RUN mkdir /app

# ソースコードをコピー
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/front-core
# アプリケーションの依存関係をインストール
RUN npm install

# ポートの公開
EXPOSE 3000

# マウントポイントの設定
VOLUME /app/front-core

# サーバーの起動
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Under sentence is backend side(Laravel) code of Routing of Breeze.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return ['Laravel' => app()->version()];
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('register');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('login');

Route::post('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.email');

Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.store');

Route::get('/verify-email/{id}/{hash}', VerifyEmailController::class)
                ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');

Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.send');

Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->middleware('auth')
                ->name('logout');
```

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mariadb:
        driver: local
```

Please help me.

1.
I expected that changed URL of frontend side request such a like
'http://0.0.0.0:80/register' to 'http://0.0.0.0:80/user/register' and 'http://0.0.0.0:80/api/register'

but error message did not change.

2.
I used curl command to check routing file's route is exist.
Command is 'curl [http://0.0.0.0:80/register'](http://0.0.0.0:80/register%27).
The command response is Error message of Laravel what message is 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for route register. Supported methods: POST. in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 122'.

3.
I run command 'sail php artisan route:list' and route is exist.

Comment: It said this in bright red letters: `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, but after that it gave you a filename, that filename is important. Did the sire load your frontend? Most likely yes, but did the site load your backend? Can you make a postman call to '/' and what is it returning

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I'd got lost info of file name.
File name is `Register.js:60`
React side do not send request to backend side.
Evidence is when React side request form data. but Laravel-log is

```
   INFO  Server running on [http://0.0.0.0:8000].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

notiong.
Setting of log is default.